# Why is the table filled with Array[0], Array[1],Array[2],Array[3] after the following SQL statement is executed?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Why is the table filled with `Array[0]`, `Array[1]`, `Array[2]`, `Array[3]` after the following SQL statement is executed?

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO choicetable (announcementid, question, option1, option2, option3, option4) 
   VALUES ('$announcementid', '$choicequestion[$j]', '$option[$j][0]', '$option[$j][1]', '$option[$j][2]', '$option[$j][3]')")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

When I `echo $option[$j][0];`, it displays the true value. But the value of `$option[$j][0]`, `$option[$j][1]`, `$option[$j][2]`, `$option[$j][3]` cannot be inserted into the table. What's wrong?

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the array elements in braces, e.g.,

```
"{$option[$j][3]}"
```

See [the PHP Manual page for strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php); it's under the heading "Variable Parsing."